# parse json to array when return laravel model

Tags: php, laravel

I have a laravel model **Course** and there is an attribute **times** has a JSON string (time table to be clear).

when I request the data in controller `$courses = Course::all()` I want to parse the `times` attribute automatically to array, this is because when I return $courses as JSON it will format the `times` to json and it is already JSON so it return non understandable string format,
so I need `times` to json_decode or to parse to array.

Is there any way to do that in the model or in the controller ??

I can do that by foreach on the `$courses` and reformat the `times` ,
but I think there must be another simple solution ...

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators seems like what you need

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting

Comment: You want a mutator, [Course::getTimesAttribute](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators).